# Slow scrolling through open tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, mouse

Today my Firefox updated to version 57. Apart from the new UI, I noticed a change that made using Firefox very hard: Scrolling through the open tabs with the mouse wheel is **much** slower than it was with all previous Firefox versions. I just measured 22 seconds to scroll from the leftmost to the rightmost tab (yes, I have a tendency to open way too many tabs).

Previous versions seem to have an accelerated scrolling, and it was easy to handle the number of tabs. Is there a way to re-activate the old accelerated scrolling behavior?

Comment: You mean the sort of changing between tabs you get from ctrl+tab ? FWIW scrolling with the wheel when cursor is positioned over the tabs doesn't have any effect for me, but I can't recall if it worked in my previous version either.

Comment: @pbhj I'm talking about the speed of scrolling the tab headers from left to right when you have more tabs open than fit on your screen. When the mouse cursor hovers over the tab headers, I can scroll them by using the mousewheel.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1403563). There has been recent activity, so hopefully it is resolved soon.

As a work-around I'm using `mousewheel.default.delta_multiplier_y = 500` in `about:config`. The drawback is that this also affects general page scrolling, which is now way too fast.

For more infos see [this reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/73q8t0/how_to_change_the_tab_scroll_speed_in_ff_quantum/).